# Find which computer a user is logged into on a domain

Tags: .net, vb.net, active-directory

Basically I want to replicate what this freeware does in vb.net

http://www.getnow.com/windows/business/databases-tools/active-directory-user-lookup

I am running a tech support software suite, and I have a list of usernames based off the caller coming in. I want to be able to use that to leverage VNC. So I want to search my Domain for the Computer name(or IP) where a user is, so I can launch VNC to control their computer for support.
While searching online I keep getting code for looking up the computer name or username for the CURRENT computer. Or to search the AD for information about a username.
I just want to grab the PC name/IP of a remote computer where a user is logged in currently.
Any help with that, or pointing in the right direction would be highly appreciated.
thanks

Comment: Huh... I imagine this would be difficult as a user can be logged into multiple machines (theoretically) and multiple users can be logged into a single machine (theoretically). Sounds like getnow might be using some custom processes running on users machines.

Comment: AD doesn't store who is logged into what machine. There are some powershell scripts available on the web that you can run and look at last logged in date / time etc. The support desk where I work settles for asking the user for a tag number or IP address of their machine and then this gets input into VNC.

Comment: We normally ask for tag numbers of a machine, but not all machine's name are based off tag numbers(don't ask) and not all users are the most keen people so this is more of a potential to eliminate time than a necessity. I was looking to see if this was even possible.